# Batch file to Schedule and Reschedule Future Shutdowns

Tags: batch-file, shutdown

I have a .bat file with some code, I want to add the following to it.:

1. Tell user is there is currently a shutdown activated (If the BAT is run more than once before shutdown) and when that shutdown is scheduled for.
2. Currently when trying to reschedule the shutdown, the BAT displays errorlevel 1990, I need a way for it not to show that message.

And I would also like to try the following (I am not too sure how to do it.)

3. if X=List, shows multiple future shutdowns scheduled (date and times), at particular dates, and also shows re-occurring scheduled shutdowns.
4. Be able to add or remove individual future shutdowns, or edit them, etc.

The code below works pretty well, but without achieving points .1 .2 and .3

I have managed to solve point .2: using 2>NUL

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto :MAIN

:INVALID
Echo X = "%input01%" is invalid.
timeout 5
goto :MAIN

:NOW
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s
Echo    Shutting down now.
pause
goto :MAIN

:STOP
Echo    Attempting to stop any Scheduled Shutdowns.
Echo/
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /a 2>NUL
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1116 (Echo    Scheduled shutdown stopped.) ELSE (
Echo    Unable to abort the system because no shutdown was in progress (1116^)
)
Timeout 10
goto :MAIN

:MAIN
cls
set "input01="
set "ExVal01="
Echo JimmyWilliams - 20180523
Echo/
Echo This will cause the computer to automatically shutdown in X minutes,
Echo and will override any existing scheduled shutdown.
Echo/
Echo Enter "X = Stop", cancel any currently active future shutdown.
Echo Enter "X = Quit", to close this program.
Echo/
Set /p "input01=1. Enter a whole positive number: X = "
if "%input01%"=="" goto :INVALID
Set /a ExVal01="%input01%"*60
if /I "%input01%"=="Quit" goto :Quit
if /I "%input01%"=="Stop" goto :STOP
if %input01%==0 goto :NOW
if %ExVal01%==0 goto :INVALID
if %input01% LSS 0 goto :INVALID
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s /t %ExVal01% 2>NUL
if ERRORLEVEL 1190 (echo    Rescheduled to shutdown in %input01% mins.
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /a
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s /t %ExVal01%
) ELSE (echo    Shutting down in %input01% mins.
)
Timeout 10
goto :MAIN
:QUIT
Echo    Quiting the Program.
pause
:EOF:
```

I am wondering why a scheduled shutdown this way is not shown in the "Task Scheduler" (Windows 10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code.

```
::20180618
::JamesShaw
::Description: This program allows users to schedule a future shutdown, and cancel them.
::
::Bug:
::  If shutdown is scheduled far into the future, and then computer is shutdown before this scheduled shutdown
::  Program will continue to say the future date even though it is no longer scheduled.
::  Remove by typing "Stop" or entering new shutdown.
::Warning: Does not show the timer when shutdown will occur.

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Checks to make sure that WMIC.EXE exists, to get date and time (independent of how the computer's time is displayed/region settings).
cls
WMIC.EXE Alias /? >NUL 2>&1 || GOTO Exe_DNE_Error
goto :CURRENT

:Exe_DNE_Error
Echo    WMIC.EXE is not installed; this program cannot obtain dates and times to show when a shutdown is scheduled until this EXE is available.
pause
goto :QUIT

:INVALID
Echo X = "%input01%" is invalid.
timeout 5
goto :CURRENT

:NOW
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s
Echo    Shutting down now.
Echo    You have a few seconds to type "Stop", if you wish.
timeout 5
goto :CURRENT

:STOP
Echo    Attempting to stop any Scheduled Shutdowns.
Echo/
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /a 2>NUL
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1116 (Echo    Scheduled shutdown stopped.) ELSE (
Echo    Unable to abort the system because no shutdown was in progress (1116^)
)
If EXIST "%~dp0Schdule Scheduler(TEMP).txt" del "%~dp0Schdule Scheduler(TEMP).txt"
timeout 5
goto :RESETSCHEDULE

:TOOLARGE
Echo X = "%input01%" is invalid.
Echo X must be less than 5256000 (10 years).
timeout 5
goto :CURRENT

:CURRENT
:: Use WMIC to retrieve current date and time.
:: Compares current time and date to the Scheduled shutdown within "Schdule Scheduler(TEMP).txt"
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%G IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
   IF "%%~L"=="" goto s_done
      Set _yyyy=%%L
      Set _mm=00%%J
      Set _dd=00%%G
      Set _hr=00%%H
      Set _mi=00%%I
)
:s_done

:: Pad digits with leading zeros
Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%
Set _dd=%_dd:~-2%
Set _hr=%_hr:~-2%
Set _mi=%_mi:~-2%

:: Display the date/time in ISO 8601 format:
Set _isodate=%_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dd% %_hr%:%_mi%
If EXIST "%~dp0Schdule Scheduler(TEMP).txt" goto :SCHEDULECHECKER
goto :RESETSCHEDULE

:SCHEDULECHECKER
set /p PulledDate=<"%~dp0Schdule Scheduler(TEMP).txt"
Set _ySch=%PulledDate:~0,4%
Set _mthS=%PulledDate:~5,2%
Set _dSch=%PulledDate:~8,2%
Set _hSch=%PulledDate:~11,2%
Set _mSch=%PulledDate:~14,2%
Set _dateSch=%_ySch%-%_mthS%-%_dSch% %_hSch%:%_mSch%

If /I %_ySch% LSS %_yyyy% goto :RESETSCHEDULE
If /I %_ySch% EQU %_yyyy% If /I %_mthS% LSS %_mm% goto :RESETSCHEDULE
If /I %_ySch% EQU %_yyyy% If /I %_mthS% EQU %_mm% If /I %_dSch% LSS %_dd% goto :RESETSCHEDULE
If /I %_ySch% EQU %_yyyy% If /I %_mthS% EQU %_mm% If /I %_dSch% EQU %_dd% If /I %_hSch% LSS %_hr% goto :RESETSCHEDULE
If /I %_ySch% EQU %_yyyy% If /I %_mthS% EQU %_mm% If /I %_dSch% EQU %_dd% If /I %_hSch% EQU %_hr% If /I %_mSch% LSS %_mi% goto :RESETSCHEDULE
goto :MAIN

:RESETSCHEDULE
If EXIST "%~dp0Schdule Scheduler(TEMP).txt" del "%~dp0Schdule Scheduler(TEMP).txt"
Set "_ySch="
Set "_mthS="
Set "_dSch="
Set "_hSch="
Set "_mSch="
Set "_dateSch="
goto :MAIN

:MAIN
cls
if "%_dateSch%"=="" (set _dateSch1=No Scheduled Shutdown.) ELSE (
Set _dateSch1=%_dateSch%
)
set "input01="
set "ExVal01="
Echo JamesShaw - 20180618
Echo/
Echo This will cause the computer to automatically shutdown in X minutes,
Echo and will override any existing scheduled shutdown.
Echo/
Echo Current clock time is: %_isodate%
Echo Shutdown scheduled at: %_dateSch1%
Echo/
Echo Enter "X = Stop", cancel any currently active future shutdown.
Echo Enter "X = Quit", to close this program.
Echo/
Set /p "input01=1. Enter a whole positive number: X = "
if "%input01%"=="" goto :INVALID
Set /a ExVal01="%input01%"*60
if /I "%input01%"=="Quit" goto :QUIT
if /I "%input01%"=="Stop" goto :STOP
if /I %input01% GEQ 5256000 GOTO :TOOLARGE
if %input01%==0 goto :NOW
if %ExVal01%==0 goto :INVALID
if %input01% LSS 0 goto :INVALID
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s /t %ExVal01% 2>NUL
if ERRORLEVEL 1190 (echo    Rescheduled to shutdown to %input01% mins from now.
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /a
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s /t %ExVal01%
) ELSE (echo    Shutdown to %input01% mins from now.
)
Set /a _mSch=input01+_mi
Set /a _hSch=_mSch/60
Set /a _mSch=_mSch%%60
Set /a _hSch=_hSch+_hr
Set /a _dSch=_hSch/24
Set /a _hSch=_hSch%%24
Set /a _dSch=_dSch+_dd
pause
goto :FEB

:FEB
::Tests to see if the month of Feburary is a leap year for that year or not.
Set /a test1=_yyyy%%4
Set /a test2=_yyyy%%100
Set /a test3=_yyyy%%400
Set /a test4="" 2>NUL
if /I %_mm% EQU 2 (
if /I %test1% EQU 0 (
if /I %test2% EQU 0 (
if /I %test3% EQU 0 (Set /a test4=29) ELSE (Set /a test4=28)
) ELSE (Set /a test4=29)
) ELSE (Set /a test4=28)

GOTO :MYBREAK
)
GOTO :MONTH31

:MONTH31
FOR %%G IN (1 3 5 7 8 10 12) DO (
if /I %_mm% EQU %%G (Set /a test4=31
GOTO :MYBREAK)
)
Set /a test4=30
GOTO :MYBREAK

:MYBREAK
if /I %_dSch% GTR %test4% (
Set /a _dSch=_dSch-test4
if /I %_mm% EQU 12 (
Set /a _yyyy=_yyyy+1
Set /a _mm=1
) ELSE (Set /a _mm=_mm+1)

GOTO :FEB
)
Set "_mSch=00%_mSch%
Set _mSch=%_mSch:~-2%
Set "_hSch=00%_hSch%
Set _hSch=%_hSch:~-2%
Set "_dSch=00%_dSch%
Set _dSch=%_dSch:~-2%
Set "_mm=00%_mm%"
Set _mm=%_mm:~-2%
:: Display the date/time in ISO 8601 format:
Set _isodate=%_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dSch% %_hSch%:%_mSch%
> "%~dp0Schdule Scheduler(TEMP).txt" Echo %_yyyy%-%_mm%-%_dSch% %_hSch%:%_mSch%
Goto :CURRENT

:QUIT
Echo    Quiting the Program.
pause
:EOF:
```

Here is another simpler version without the calendar and timer of the scheduled shutdown
(works without the EXE).

```
::20180527
::JamesShaw
::Description: This program allows users to schedule a future shutdown, and cancel them.
::
::Warning: Does not show the timer when shutdown will occur

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto :MAIN

:INVALID
Echo X = "%input01%" is invalid.
timeout 5
goto :MAIN

:NOW
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s
Echo    Shutting down now.
pause
goto :MAIN

:STOP
Echo    Attempting to stop any Scheduled Shutdowns.
Echo/
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /a 2>NUL
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1116 (Echo    Scheduled shutdown stopped.) ELSE (
Echo    Unable to abort the system because no shutdown was in progress (1116^)
)
Timeout 10
goto :MAIN

:MAIN
cls
set "input01="
set "ExVal01="
Echo JamesShaw - 20180523
Echo/
Echo This will cause the computer to automatically shutdown in X minutes,
Echo and will override any existing scheduled shutdown.
Echo/
Echo Enter "X = Stop", cancel any currently active future shutdown.
Echo Enter "X = Quit", to close this program.
Echo/
Set /p "input01=1. Enter a whole positive number: X = "
if "%input01%"=="" goto :INVALID
Set /a ExVal01="%input01%"*60
if /I "%input01%"=="Quit" goto :Quit
if /I "%input01%"=="Stop" goto :STOP
if %input01%==0 goto :NOW
if %ExVal01%==0 goto :INVALID
if %input01% LSS 0 goto :INVALID
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s /t %ExVal01% 2>NUL
if ERRORLEVEL 1190 (echo    Rescheduled to shutdown in %input01% mins.
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /a
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /s /t %ExVal01%
) ELSE (echo    Shutting down in %input01% mins.
)
Timeout 10
goto :MAIN
:QUIT
Echo    Quiting the Program.
pause
:EOF:
```